# Is there a term for repeated phrases (not a catch-phrase)?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There is a children's television program called "Ben & Holly" in which there are a few repeated phrases/themes. I'm trying to find the correct terminology to describe them.

Example 1: In almost every episode there is a variation of a phrase - usually "and I'm an elf" or "and we're elves", followed by the elf/elves blowing a horn.

Example 2: About once every 5 episodes a location is flooded with jelly and all the characters all shout "Jelly flood!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**motif** should work for this.

> a dominant or recurring idea in an artistic work.

Just found another possibility, **epanalepsis**, courtesy of a rhetorical devices page on [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/rhetoric-and-rhetorical-devices#980zzLGOBTMyu5oY.99).

> repetition of the same word or phrase after other words have intervened.

Thought of another one as well: **trope**.

> The word trope has also come to be used for describing commonly recurring literary and rhetorical devices, motifs or clichés in creative works.

Comment: Thanks. That was my initial thought - I think it works well for describing the idea of, for example, the jelly flood, but I'm wondering if there isn't a more fitting word to describe repeated phrases.

Comment: The only other one I've been able to find so far is anaphora, but that's more the repetition of words/phrases at the beginning of several successive verses/clauses/paragraphs and isn't really what you wanted. (just edited the answer with another possibility I found)

Comment: If it's not so much the motif you want to describe, but actual text, would 'idiomatic expression' cover the bill? (From [Freedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiomatic+expression): *locution, saying, expression - a word or phrase that particular people use in particular situations; "pardon the expression"*)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [**buzz phrase**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buzz%20phrase) if your children keep repeating them. It means:

> a fashionable phrase in widespread use, a **voguish phrase**: '“*Customer for life” is becoming an off-repeated buzz phrase.*'

[Merriam-Webster]